# How to upload and create multiple file objects with django

Tags: file-upload, image-uploading

I'm new to Django and I'm on the first stages for writing a web app. One of the features of the app requires users to upload multiple pictures to a database.

I have created an 'image' model for storing the pictures and later manipulate them. The user is supposed to upload more than one image at a time using a POST request (don't even know if that is possible). 
Each picture uploaded is supposed to be an image object on the database, but for some reason, I'm failing to upload and also create that object. Nothing happens when I make the POST request. I might be failing at some point and in something simple. I'd appreciate some help.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class image(models.Model):

    image_field = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import image

class images_form(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = image
        fields = ['image_field']

        widgets = {
            'image_field' : forms.ClearableFileInput(
                attrs={'class': 'upload ','inputtype':'file','name':'images','multiple':True })}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import images_form
from .models import image

def upload_files(request):

    context = {'images_form': images_form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_images = images_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        if form_images.is_valid():

            for file in files:
                newimg = image(image_field = file)
                print(newimg.name)
                newimg.save()

            return HttpResponse('images uploaded')

    else:

        return render(request, 'master_form/desk.html', context=context)
```

**upload_images.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Django Desk</h1>


    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1> images</h1>

  <form method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ images_form.as_p }}


  <button type = "submit"> Upload </button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was.

```
 files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
```

Was empty or didn't exist.

You have to use the same name you used when defining your model fields, in my case 'image_field', not 'images'.

The new code looks like this (views.py):

```
 for file in request.FILES.getlist('image_field'):
            img = image(image_field=file)
            img.save()
```